# Convert.ToString() error message : The parameters Year, Month an day describe a DateTime which cannot be represented. But my data is not a date?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have an unexplained error on a `Convert.ToString()` while processing a column from a DataReader.

My "VALID" column just contains "0" or "1" in a string.

Could it be that the method wants to treat my data as a date?

The Error message is

> The parameters Year, Month and Day describe a DateTime which cannot be represented

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

[image]

Comment: try reading your `ObjDataReader["VALID"]` into a variable and look at it in the debugger - just to be sure. also: if it _is_ a string, wouldn't casting it (instead of converting) be enough?

Comment: Maybe try [Boolean.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.parse?view=netcore-3.1) instead of Convert.

Comment: What is the type of  `ObjDataReader["VALID"]` (i.e.`ObjDataReader["VALID"].GetType()`)? Perhaps that might help to take the next step in debugging the issue. (Also, it may make most sense to store a true/false aka yes/no value in a `BIT` column in SQL Server, and convert it to a `bool` in C# - assuming you are using SQL Server, and assuming you have control over that.)

Comment: Hello, my "VALID" column is really of type string.

The "VALID" member of my business object is also a type string. It's just a classic unbox since "ObjDataReader [" VALID "]" returns an object.

Comment: Maybe there is a second parameter to pass to the "ToString" method?

Comment: @JchristopheCherid, can you tell me how do you define the VALID in the database?

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT  In the database that i'm reading ( "SELECT...."),  "VALID" is define like a string. But this string contains "0" or "1".

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT  tObjMpfDes.ADR_PV = Convert.ToString(ObjDataReader["ADR_PV"]);   What's crazy is that this code works for this column.

And for the "VALID" column, the compiler crashes when talking about date ??

Comment: That exception message is generated most often by calling the `DateTime(int,int,int)` constructor, and possibly a few other places that call `DateTime`s [`DateToTicks`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,891f8af5025ab2f3) function. It's not being generated by `Convert.ToString`. You need to examine the exception's stack trace to work our where/how that call is being made.

Comment: Now it's OK (!). I really don't understand why...It's weird, to see worrying especially when there is no logical reason.  Anyway, many Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Check your tobjmpfDes.Valid property may be you use date type in valid after fetching data from db converted into string you are saving in date type format that's why this issue is Rising